Node.js Azure app service deployed with github actions returns 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page' error
so i built a node.js app which basically makes api calls and serves an index.html page. and i made it an azure app service (not sure if i worded that correctly).
initially, i deployed it from my local machine just to test. and it worked. when i opened the url, it led me to the index.html page in the public folder. all api calls were working correctly too.
i was now ready to deploy using github actions (since it worked fine when the source code was from my local pc). i did, and it built and deployed successfully.
i initially assumed it worked fine since it worked with the local source code.
but today (a couple of days later), i decided to open the base url in a browser (used postman too) and i got:
'You do not have permission to view this directory or page'.
also, all api endpoints return this:
'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'
when i checked the deployment summary on github, there was one warning in the build step under annotations:
'The following actions uses Node.js version which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node20: actions/setup-node@v3.'
this is what i've tried so far:
i was using node 18.20.02.
i switched to node 21.3.0, updated the workflow to use it, and also updated the app service's runtime stack to ~21 but nothing has changed. the warning on github is still the same too.
i enabled app logs for the app service on Azure and viewed them but it was just 404 and 403 errors below.
when i enter the base url
2024-08-14 11:27:27 CLEANING-SERVICES-SYSTEM-API GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=7633cd2c-65ba-4eb1-9b04-7d57170bb6d0 443 - 197.251.193.117 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/127.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/127.0.0.0 ARRAffinity=c015407f2340ab83319171108305fa1072c8452284bc5ef903dfd906b4fd7902;+ARRAffinitySameSite=c015407f2340ab83319171108305fa1072c8452284bc5ef903dfd906b4fd7902 - cleaning-services-system-api.azurewebsites.net 403 14 0 422 1664 33

when accessing any endpoint:
2024-08-14 11:32:19 CLEANING-SERVICES-SYSTEM-API GET /admin/bookings X-ARR-LOG-ID=44a0a6fa-15b4-484d-aaa8-a89135510ab9 443 - 197.251.193.117 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/127.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/127.0.0.0 ARRAffinity=c015407f2340ab83319171108305fa1072c8452284bc5ef903dfd906b4fd7902;+ARRAffinitySameSite=c015407f2340ab83319171108305fa1072c8452284bc5ef903dfd906b4fd7902 - cleaning-services-system-api.azurewebsites.net 404 0 2 470 1680 28

before, with the local source code, i could see all app logs when i make requests - the response, console logs, etc.
this is my index.js file
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./src/database/database');
const adminRouter = require('./src/routes/adminRoutes');
const customerRouter = require('./src/routes/customerRoutes');

const path = require('path');

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT;

const checkPort = async (port) => {
    if (port === undefined) {
        console.error("PORT is not defined in .env file.");
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

checkPort(port);

// Routes
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/customer', customerRouter);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

any idea why this is happening? what do i do?

Share complete error logs.

If possible, share your GitHub repository?

Are you deploying Linux or windows?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@AsleshaKantamsetti i'm deploying Windows. I can't share the GitHub repo unfortunately because i'm kind of doing this for a client as a school project. i've added the app logs to the question

@xirehat i've added logs and my index.js contents to the question now thanks

I created a node.js app using express and deployed to the Azure Windows App service without problem.

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.


To resolve above issue, I have added the start command to the scripts in package.json.

"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }

package.json:
{
  "name": "nodeapp7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  }
}


I have added the process.env.PORT in index.js as shown below.

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

index.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!');
});
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  ];
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/items', (req, res) => {
  const newItem = req.body;
  data.push(newItem);
  res.status(201).json(newItem);
});
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  res.json(data);
});
app.get('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const item = data.find((item) => item.id === id);
  if (!item) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Item not found' });
  } else {
    res.json(item);
  }
});
app.put('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const updatedItem = req.body;
  const index = data.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  if (index === -1) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Item not found' });
  } else {
    data[index] = { ...data[index], ...updatedItem };
    res.json(data[index]);
  }
});
app.delete('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
      const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
      const index = data.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      if (index === -1) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Item not found' });
      } else {
        const deletedItem = data.splice(index, 1);
        res.json(deletedItem[0]);
      }
});

When deploying to the windows app service set the SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true in environment variables of Azure App Service.

Azure App Service Output:




i've done everything you've said already except setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true so i did that but i ended up with 'This page isn't working at the momentcleaning-services-system-api.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500'

@ackainu Have you deployed your Database to azure?

yes. azure cosmos db for mongodb

@ackainu How do you connect database to your Azure Web App?

i used the connection string that was provided for the db in the azure portal. I put it in my .env file in my node.js app and connected to it using mongoose.connect

@ackainu Check once Log stream of Azure web app

Wed Aug 14 2024 12:38:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:SyntaxError: Unexpected token >at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)at Object..js (module.js:464:10)at Module.load (module.js:353:31)at Function._load (module.js:311:12)at Module.require (module.js:359:17)at require (module.js:375:17)at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)at Object..js (module.js:464:10)at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
